# Count Items in a sharepoint list programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

This is my table
Type     Time   Month
A   Yes Jan
A   Yes Feb
A   No  Mar
A   Yes Apr

This is what I get in return:
Month YES NO
Jan  1 0
Feb  2 0
Mar  0 3
Apr  0 4

What I want is for my count of to look like this:

Month YES NO
Jan  1 0
Feb  1 0
Mar  0 1
Apr  1 0

Here is my script.  I'm racking my head and any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```
<Script>
function processResult(xData, status) {


    var Month = [];
    var i = 0;  
var TableRow = "<table>"; 

    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
    var sType = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
    var sTime = $(this).attr("ows_Time");
    var sMonth = $(this).attr("ows_Month");
    i = i + 1;


if(Month[sMonth]==undefined)
{
Month[sMonth] = [0,0,0,0];
}
if(Month[sMonth]!=undefined)
{   
if (sTime == "Yes" && sType == "A"){Month[sMonth][0] = i}
if (sTime == "No" && sType == "A"){Month[sMonth][1] = i}
}


});
 var key = "";
    for(key in Month){
           TableRowHtml += "<TR><td style='text-align: Left'> " + key +" </td><td>" + Month[key][0] + "</td><td> "+ Month[key][1] + "</td><TR>";
            }

TableRowHtml +="</Table>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(TableRowHtml);
 }
</Script>
```

Thanks

Comment: SharePoint 2007 or 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `var i;` definition into the `each` function; right now you're using the same `i` for each row, thus it's cumulative. Beware the closure.

(Wait, what even *is* `i`? It doesn't seem to do anything useful, if you're not *trying* to keep it cumulative.)

Also not really sure how you're creating a well-formed table, seems like you're missing the first `<table>` tag. In any case, see below (untested).

```
<Script>
function processResult(xData, status) {
    var Month = [];

    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        var sType = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
        var sTime = $(this).attr("ows_Time");
        var sMonth = $(this).attr("ows_Month");
        i = i + 1;

        if (Month[sMonth] == undefined) {
            Month[sMonth] = [0,0,0,0];
        } else if (sType == "A") {
            var which = sTime == "Yes" ? 0 : 1;
            Month[sMonth][which] = i;
        }
    });

    var table = "<table>"; 
    for (var key in Month) {
        table += "<TR><td style='text-align: Left'> " + key +" </td>"
               + "<td>" + Month[key][0] + "</td><td> "+ Month[key][1] + "</td><TR>";
    }
    table += "</table>";

    $("#tasksUL").append(table);
}
</Script>
```

Comment: Dave, Thanks for your prompt response.  I don't understand the sTime == "Yes ? 0:1;  
Can you clarify?
Thanks

Comment: @MD18358 Sure. That's a [ternary expression](http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/ternary-example.htm) and just means if `sTime` is "Yes", `which` will be 0, otherwise 1. Then `which` is used to decide which month array entry is set to `i` (although as both Manuel and I noticed, using `i` is probably unnecessary, and wrong, unless you move the `var` into the closure).

Comment: Hi Dave; I've been racking my head over this and Manuel's input. Your approach works for the narrow scope of a yes/no in a single month.  I have several months and other items to count.  I was hoping for a more dynamic script to use an "if statments" to count items from a list.  I greatly appreciate your assistance I hope I've clarified my need.

Comment: @MD18358 You'll have to describe what you actually want, then; if you *do* want it cumulative then you'll need a counter for each individual month, and instead of setting `Month[sMonth][which]` to 0 or 1, you'd add 1 to the current contents of `Month[sMonth][which]`.

Comment: Hey good morning!  I thought by keeping my request simple, I could adapt the concept. Anyhow...OK lets start over.  I have a list of  Yes, No, N/A spread over months.  I need the script to provide a summarized count of each Yes, No, N/A for each month.  So for eaxample: Jan had 6 yes, 3 No, 2 N/A. Feb had 2 No, 9 Yes, 4 N/A.

Comment: @MD18358 My previous comment described how to do that.

Comment: @Manuel
I've been recking my head on this becuase it has not worked 
So where Manuel offered this:
if (sTime == "Yes" && sType == "A"){Month[sMonth][0] = 1} 
if (sTime == "No" && sType == "A"){Month[sMonth][1] = 0}

The fix is:
if (sTime == "Yes" && sType == "A"){Month[sMonth][0] = Month[sMonth][0]+1} 
if (sTime == "No" && sType == "A"){Month[sMonth][1] = Month[sMonth][1]+1}

Thanks again for giving me your time and I'm soooo happy it works now.
regards,
MD18358

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
if (sTime == "Yes" && sType == "A"){Month[sMonth][0] = 1}
if (sTime == "No" && sType == "A"){Month[sMonth][1] = 0}
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, Dave; Look at Karl's script.  Its close to what I was trying to achieve.  The variables could be interchangable for anything from the list.  The problem is that I don't get a Summary count, I only get a list replacing numbers where the item was before.